# Angular way to Show Hide Divs similar to Tabs but without Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to achieve Tabs like functionality using Divs whose Div Id is generated using ng-repeat.

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
   <div id="div{{$index}}" class="targetDiv" ng-show="setSomething" ng-repeat="question in Questions">
       <h3>{{question.question}}</h3>

        <button style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 4px; padding-bottom: 2px;" class="btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="answers in question.Answers">
                  {{answers.AnswerText}}
        </button>

        <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSomething()">Next</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I've tried so many ways and even tried googling similar things, but I could not achieve it, may because of limited knowledge of AngularJs. I'm trying to achieve somthing like the following image. Remember each picture represents a DIV and when you click on NEXT current DIV hides and DIV with second question Shows up .  .[image: Div1] 
[image: Div2]

Controller Code:

```
  $scope.showonlyone = function (divToShow) {
        angular.forEach($scope.Questions, function (que, i) {
            if (divToShow == 'div' + i) {
                //$scope.Questions.splice(que, 1);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })
    };
```

Comment: You are on the right track with your setSomething and doSomething(). Can you post the javascript you have for these two functions so I can create an answer out of it? I'd like to see what you already have before continuing.

Comment: Here is my Controller code :
      $scope.showonlyone = function (divToShow) {
            angular.forEach($scope.Questions, function (que, i) {
                if (divToShow == 'div' + i) {
                    //$scope.Questions.splice(que, 1);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            })
        };

Comment: Thanks Blackunknown for a quick response. Frankly.. I really dont know what to set and where....

Comment: Can you put the controller code neatly formatted inside a code block with an edit? So that future visitors can see your code in one look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="targetDiv" ng-show="($index == selectedIndex)" ng-repeat="question in Questions">
       <h3>{{question.question}}</h3>

        <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" ng-click="selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1">Next</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

By the way if u want to show 1 question u dont need ng-repeat:

```
<div class="targetDiv">
   <h3>{{questions[selectedIndex].question}}</h3>

   <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" ng-click="selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you run out of index by clicking next? Your second solution has no check if you are still within bounds.

Comment: Yes, of course, there should be also something like ng-disabled="selectedIndex > questions.length - 2"... but this is out of scope of this question

Comment: Not entirely true, while it doesn't check in this case the ng-show will prevent the next button from showing up. So you can never end up out of bounds. :D

Comment: Based on the edit of your comment, you are right about the scope, can't hurt to warn him though. Lowe seems to make the same risky change to his html in his answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Petr Averyanov and Blackunknown for helping me out. Its the perfect fit for my requirement. I'm actually a hardcore backend developer and used to scare Javascript too much. But I think I'm in love with Angular. I hope to digg more deeper into it.. Thanks again. I'm sure I will soon see you all  again :) .

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
.controller('QuestionListController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.activeIndex = 0;

    $scope.next = function () {
        if ($scope.activeIndex === ($scope.Questions.length - 1)) {
            alert("finished");
        } else {
            $scope.activeIndex = $scope.activeIndex + 1;
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="QuestionListController">
    <div ng-repeat="question in Questions" ng-if="$index == activeIndex">
        ...
    </div>
    <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

But you might wanna consider putting this into a directive.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work although I haven't tested it inside a real environment:

```
$scope.setActive = function(index) {
  $scope.selectedQuestionIndex = index + 1;
}

$scope.isActive = function(index) {
  return index == $scope.selectedQuestionIndex;
}
```

With your html being:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <div id="div{{$index}}" class="targetDiv" ng-show="isActive($index)" ng-repeat="question in Questions">
    <h3>{{question.question}}</h3>

    <button style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 4px; padding-bottom: 2px;" class="btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="answers in question.Answers">
              {{answers.AnswerText}}
    </button>

    <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" ng-click="setActive($index)">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will sute you

```
<div class="col-md-10" ng-init="firstQuestion()">
    <div ng-repeat="question in Questions" class="targetDiv" ng-show="$index == currentQuestionIndex">
        <h3>{{question.question}}</h3>

        <button style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 4px; padding-bottom: 2px;" class="btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="answers in question.Answers">
            {{answers.AnswerText}}
        </button>

        <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSomething()" ng-show = "currentQuestionIndex < Questions.length - 1">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

with js like

```
$scope.firstQuestion = function () {
            $scope.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        };

        $scope.doSomething = function () {
            if ($scope.currentQuestionIndex < $scope.Questions.length)
                $scope.currentQuestionIndex += 1;
        }
```

---

Or something like this

```
<div class="col-md-10" ng-init="firstQuestion()">    
    <h3>{{question.question}}</h3>

    <button style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 4px; padding-bottom: 2px;" class="btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="answers in question.Answers">
        {{answers.AnswerText}}
    </button>

    <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSomething()" ng-show = "currentQuestionIndex < Questions.length - 1">Next</a>
</div>
```

with js

```
$scope.firstQuestion = function () {
            $scope.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
            $scope.question = $scope.Questions[$scope.currentQuestionIndex];
        };

        $scope.doSomething = function () {
            if ($scope.currentQuestionIndex < $scope.Questions.length) {
                $scope.currentQuestionIndex += 1;
                $scope.question = $scope.Questions[$scope.currentQuestionIndex];
            }
        }
```